# How to explode an object in 2.8

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

This might be a silly question, but I'm not sure how to use rigid bodies in 2.8 to explode a cube.  I'm trying to make it active and the plane passive as well but can't figure out how.

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Stick a force in the middle of the cube, that'll blow it to smithereens

Comment: Dang it doesn't work.  It should though...I think there's a problem with the pieces being stuck together because they are not even falling apart when I press play on the timeline.

Comment: Yeah they have to be seperate pieces.  they must not be *glued* together (just like real life).  Soft bodies are a little different, the can be part of the same object.

Comment: You also need to dial up the force quite high

Comment: Oh that worked!  Yes all I had to do was crank up the force to 1000